# How to avoid underlined words and commands in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

In Atom, why do I have all these words and commands underlined in my package.json file? How to avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was seeing the same thing La Page PT. I found that I was able to get the underlining to stop by changing the Syntax Theme away from One Dark.

File → Settings → Themes → Syntax Theme:

[Atom Themes Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSWi3.png)

I changed the Syntax Theme to Atom Dark, and I'm no longer seeing my json with the underlines:

[No More Underlines! YaY!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUAFO.png)

Comment: Ha! Great, but it looks like they updated Atom last night, and sorted out that underlining from the One Dark Syntax Theme.

Answer (score 1):

Release v1.38.1 (2019-06-13) has fixed this for me. Now I can use One Dark theme again. They have "Fixed a regression in JSON syntax highlighting that applied hyperlink styling to non-hyperlinks atom/language-json#76"

Comment: This should be the excepted answer, since it's a solution not a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Atom automatically underlines class names. Drawn from [a github issue](https://github.com/steelbrain/linter-ui-default/issues/285):

You can edit text styles in your styles.less file.

For example, try adding this:

```
atom-text-editor.editor .linter-highlight, .linter-highlight {
  &.linter-info, &.linter-warning, &.linter-error {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. But sorry! It doesn't work for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Edited answer with new suggestion (and changed link)... actually tested this one

Comment: Sorry. Still doesn't work... But your code is impressing. May be I have installed a custom package who makes the problem?... Grrr. Thanks